# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined - Django with adminlte2

Tags: jquery, django, django-templates, pycharm, adminlte

I don't have much experience with Django and even less with jQuery.

I'm currently building an app using Django 3.0 and installed django-adminlte2 to put a nice skin on it. However, I seemingly cannot get jQuery to work with extended templates. I've tried adding a line to print out something at the top of the templates, but it only works when I have jQuery defined in the same template.

I have made sure that STATIC_URL and STATIC_ROOT have been defined in settings.py and are point to the correct location.

Here is the code that includes the file with the definitions (this is in base.html):

```
{% block javascript %}
{% include 'adminlte/lib/_scripts.html' %}
{% endblock %}
```

The file itself:

```
{% load static %}
{% block scripts %}
<script src="{% static "jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" 
%}"></script>
<script src="{% static "jquery/dist/jquery-ui.min.js" 
%}"></script>
<!-- Resolve conflict in jQuery UI tooltip with 
Bootstrap tooltip -->
<script>
$.widget.bridge('uibutton', $.ui.button);
</script>
<script src="{% static 
"bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" %} "></script>
<script src="{% static "admin-lte/dist/js/app.min.js" 
%}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Where I'm trying to use jQuery:

```
{% extends "adminlte/base.html" %}
<script>let sg_v2 = $('<div>daughter jQuery is 
okay</div>'); console.log(sg_v2.text())</script>
```

I debug it with Pycharm and get "**Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined**".

If I boot up my django project and go to the site with Chrome dev tools, I see that 'jquery.min.js' and 'jquery-ui.min.js' are both in my sources and in the html of the elements tab.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: I misunderstood your question at first.  Are you saying that the jQuery script **won't work at all**, or are you only getting an error in PyCharm?

Comment: The jQuery wasn't working at all on pages that extend base.html. I just used PyCharm to get that error message.